# Словосочетание «новое обновление»

Tags: выбор-слов

Собственно говоря, возник такой вопрос: а возможно ли вообще такое словосочетание? Слово *обновление* (корень *нов*) содержит в себе значение чего-то нового. Если мы добавляем определение к нему, то у нас получается плеоназм (излишество). Но так ли это на деле? Возьмем, к примеру, предложение. «Ты видел новое обновление?». Правомерно ли здесь употреблять это словосочетание? Раз разговор идет сейчас, значит и в вопросе может спрашиваться только о чём-то новом. А теперь другой случай. Есть перечень всех обновлений ([см.](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Patches/ru) здесь). В этом списке представлены все обновления, которые когда-либо выходили за несколько лет. В списке могут быть как старые обновления, так **новые** обновления. В этом случае возможна ли такая лексическая сочетаемость? Пока оформлял вопрос, понял, что есть другой вариант: написать *недавнее обновление*.

Хотелось бы услышать мнение других.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По мне – нормально. А "писать письмо" – тоже "тавтология". Так что, если нужен ответ именно на вопрос, допустимо ли такое сочетание, то однозначно да. Слово "обновление" в контексте айтишников давно перестало восприниматься как имеющее однозначную смысловую связь с "новый", "новизна" и стало чем-то самодостаточным.

Другое дело, обязательно ли употреблять такие обороты? Конечно, "очередное" или "последнее" звучит лучше, да и сам термин "обновление" (как перевод "апгрейда"/"апдейта") мне, признаться, не очень нравится, но тут уж выбирать не приходится.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы это не походило на "новую новость", по такому поводу достаточно сказать "последнее обновление" или "очередное обновление".

**P.S.** Ещё возможны ситуации, когда нужно сопоставить обновления по степени "свежести". Тогда вместо "более нового обновления" предпочтительно "более *позднее* обновление".

Answer (score 1):

Прикол в том, что по-английски это звучит как new update, то есть никакой тавтологии, отсюда, видимо, и все проблемы, но мы же не англичане)